# connecting and separating string inputs

Tags: python, string

need help with taking inputs in a a loop like so.

```
example = input("enter the example !")
```

Then I need to add that input to one single variable and later print it all out
on separate lines EG:

```
loop cycle 1:
enter the example ! test1
loop cycle 2:
enter the example ! test2
loop cycle 3: 
enter the example ! test3
```

inputs:

```
1. test1
2. test2
3. test3
```

One thing is that I am unable to use .append due to using lists in my case is 
not in max efficiency. (probably will need to be taught to use \n)

Comment: Is this some kind of homework assignment? Are you using Python 3? If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can append new line character to input function

**for python2.**

```
example = ""
for i in range(1,4):   
    example = example + str(i)+". " +raw_input("enter the example !") +"\n"
print example
```

**for python3**

```
example = ""
for i in range(1,4):   
    example = example + str(i)+". " +input("enter the example !") +"\n"
print (example)
```

output

```
messi@messi-Hi-Fi-B85S3:~/Desktop/soc$ python sample.py 
enter the example !text 1
enter the example !text 2
enter the example !text 2
1. text 1
2. text 2
3. text 2
```

Comment: i am currently testing this and so far it is working out. I will test a bit more and if it works out i will make your answer the solution.

Comment: thats sounds great

Comment: how would i add the 1. 2. 3. etc at the start of each line ?

Comment: sorry to bug you again but how would this : example = example + str(i)+". " +raw_input("enter the example !") +"\n" look in pseudo code

Comment: please check my output . i have edited answer

Comment: seems you are sing python 3

Comment: woops i clicked the arrow thing next to the comment 0_0 anyways do you know how to convert it to pseudo code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can append the additional inputs onto the same string using the `+=` operator

You will however need to declare the variable before using `+=` for the first time

For example:

```
example = ""

for num in range(1,4):
    print "loop cycle {}:".format(num)
    example += "{}. {}".format(num, input("enter the example !"))
    if num < 3:
        example += "\n"

print example
```

*edit: updated to include conditional new lines and input numbers*

Comment: how would i add the 1. 2. 3. etc at the start of each line ? (when printing out)

Comment: updated to include the loop numbers